# Codename one: how to do live streaming

Tags: codenameone

I want to display my webcams stream by typing his url in BrowserComponent of codeName one.

Since one week i'm trying to do it but my BrowserComponent display a plain text instead of image cam.

But if i'm trying in other standard browser like Firefox it works fine, i can cleary see my cam.

So I want to know if there is a solution to display liveStreaming with codeName one Browser. 
If yes please where can I find a sample or and example ?

thanks

Comment: Are you trying in the device or the simulator? The simulator doesn't faithfully represent the way complex HTML can act on the device. Does the webcam use flash? If so it won't work anywhere

Comment: Hi I'm trying with the simulator

Comment: Are you using the Simulator? (Probably) that's why it doesn't work. Try your code on a real (recent) device. Use cross-browser compatible HTML5. For example, in my experience "JWPlayer" is very portable (I have a free license), but there are also other free open-source solutions.

Comment: Hi @FrancescoGalgani thanks for your reply but I wonder how can I integrate JWPlayer in codeName one BrowserComponent. Is there a tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Your request can be implemented in a lot of several ways. I'm not sure that using the `BrowserComponent` is the best option, however the coding with `BrowserComponent` is quite simple.

First of all, you have to implement a web page on your domain that plays the video with a full cross-compatible HTML5 player. There are several commercial and free solution with different degrees of complexity and cost.

In my comment to your question, I mentioned "JWPlayer", however yesterday I've checked that (unfortunately) a JWPlayer free license like mine (that allows me to self-host the player) is not more available to the new users. To be more precise, following the launch of JW8 in October 2017, self-hosting the player is now only available to Enterprise customers.

However, to show you an easy solution, I registered a free 30 day trial account on DaCast, that provides a player for your videos on demand and for your live streamings. In the backend of DaCast, I uploaded a sample video and then I got the code to use the player, that is similar to the following (I obfuscated the `id`):

```
<script id="xxxxxx_x_xxxxxx" width="590" height="431" src="//player.dacast.com/js/player.js"  class="dacast-video"></script>
```

Then that code can be integrated in a simple web page like the following (note that it will not work in local, you have to host it in your server):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script id="xxxxxx_x_xxxxxx" width="590" height="431" src="//player.dacast.com/js/player.js"  class="dacast-video"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After that, you can create your `BrowserComponent`:

```
Form hi = new Form("Video test", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
if (BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported()) {
    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.setURL("https://www.yourdomain.com/test.html");
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
} else {
    hi.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, "Your device is not supported");
}
hi.show();
```

I tested that this solution works on a real Android. Of course, this answer is only a tip for you and something that you can easily replicate and test, I'm not going to advertise any specific commercial service.

Comment: Hi Francesco Galgani and thanks for your reply. But with this solution I am obliged to publish my videos and my live streaming on the internet. However I want a solution that can also work in a local network with private IP addresses.

Comment: In that case, I suppose that you need to implement a local web and streaming server and to host an html5 player in your local server. Or you can include a local html5 player in your app using the `browserComponent.setURLHierarchy("/htmlFile.html");` as documented here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_browsercomponent_hierarchy

Comment: I read what is written but I admit that it is not very explicit. what is the relationship between the player and the html file?
In the following statement: browserComponent.setURLHierarchy ("/ htmlFile.html"); What is htmlFile.html? it is the html file which must contain the player?
can I host this file on my local web server?
Do I have to replace the /htmlFile.html by the path of my player? if yes, which player is it?
Here is a piece of html code that I wrote to read the video, it works with VoD but not with live streaming: <video id="video" src="url" controls preload="metadata"/>

Comment: Hi I have a camera with a microphone and a speaker.
I want to make a full duplex audio communication between the browser of a terminal equipment and this camera.
Is it possible with codeName one?
If so, can I have a tutorial?

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question. Please also consider to accept an answer if it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using `BrowserComponent.setURLHierarchy()`

1. Create a folder named `html` and place it in the folder `/src` of your Codename One project. That means that your HTML5 player will be placed in an html file inside the folder `/src/html`. If you use Netbeans IDE, that folder will be shown as a package of your project.
2. Implement your player (for example in `/src/html/player.html`). As a suggestion, you can use the free open-source solution [videojs-http-streaming](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming) + [video.js](https://videojs.com/): if you have done a right implementation, it should work with a browser. Note that you can add to `/src/html/` all the files needed by the player.
3. In your app, use code similar to the following.

Code:

```
Form hi = new Form("Video player", new BorderLayout());
if (BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported()) {
    BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
    browser.setURLHierarchy("/player.html");
    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
}
hi.show();
```

That's all. Of course the hardest part is to implement the HTML5 player: if your app can connect to the Internet, an easy solution can be the use of the CDNs, using the code samples provided in the linked pages of videojs-http-streaming.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
Francesco Galgani, I'm going to implement that! it answers my previous question.